# Alert that a WPF UserControl's dependency property must be set?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I often find that when I create WPF user controls, it is because I need to expose a couple of additional dependency properties. Typically, those properties must be set for the control to work in its intended way, and there is no meaningful default value (because, for example, the property will always be bound to something else).

When it comes to using/consuming those controls, especially a week or more after creating the user control, I never really remember what properties I need to set in the markup.

I can't imagine any way to make these "required" in the XAML editor, but is there a good/standard place from which to throw a meaningful exception if/when the property has not been set?

Comment: Is there already a better solution available?

Answer (score 0):

You could add them to a "Required" designer category so you can at least find them later.

Mark the CLR property with `[Category("Blah")]` attribute.

Lame but it might suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Create null objects and set them to the default value when creating the `DependencyProperty`. Then the null objects could be configured to give a visual hint at design time. Could be a solution in some cases?